# 'Wi-Fi adapter not found please make sure your Wi-Fi adapter is plugged in"

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless

So I once installed ubuntu on my laptop as a dual boot with windows 10. But when I open ubuntu for some reason I can't connect to Wi-Fi... It says "No Wi-Fi adapter found please make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged in and turned on". But when I open Windows Wi-Fi works perfectly fine. So if anybody could help that would be great.  Wifi adapter : Realtek. Wifi modum : Rogers ignite internet.

```
                  -Things I tried-
           1. Disabling secure boot
           2. Updating drivers/reinstalling (using synaptic)
           3. Running codes through the terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

You state, "I once installed [U]buntu on my laptop." That implies you did this some time ago and have not used it. What **version** of Ubuntu are you using? If it's an old version, i.e., 18.04 or earlier, update to a modern version (20.04 LTS or newer) that might have drivers for your WiFi modem.

What **make and *model*** is your WiFi modem? Sometimes, Ubuntu does not have a suitable open-source driver, and you might have to look online for either the manufacturer's WiFi driver or a third-party driver.

Without enough information, it's hard to provide help.